# How to get the count of similar records along with the number of results in select statement using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Given the following T-SQL query and the result below,

```
select 
    Tag
from 
    [dbo].[_StanwellAlarms_U3]
where 
    [TimeStamp] >= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19), '2013-06-06 00:00:00') 
    and [TimeStamp] < CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19), '2018-06-16 00:10:00') 
    and T = 'A' and RG = 'R'
```

**Result**

[image]

I'm struggling to create a select statement that will return the number of result and a count of similar (group) tag.

For example:

Based on the 35 records, I expect the result would yield the following result:

```
Tag                     TagCount  TotalRows 
-------------------------------------------------
T3HYY10EW100-H.ZV02.OUT    8        35
T3LFN40AA008..COM          2        35
...                        ..       ..
```

I know this is a noob SQL related question, sorry for I'm just starting to learn T-SQL, so please bear with me.

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear what the logic is which would lead to only two unique tags in your result set, but a simple count aggregation query might be what you have in mind:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM [dbo].[_StanwellAlarms_U3]
    WHERE
        [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2013-06-06 00:00:00' AND '2018-06-16 00:10:00' AND
        T = 'A' and RG = 'R'
)

SELECT
    Tag,
    COUNT(*) AS TagCount,
    (SELECT cnt FROM cte) AS TotalRows
FROM [dbo].[_StanwellAlarms_U3]
WHERE
    [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2013-06-06 00:00:00' AND '2018-06-16 00:10:00' AND
    T = 'A' and RG = 'R'
GROUP BY Tag
```

Comment: thanks for your comment.  The two unique tags are just a sample.  The expected result will group those unique tags along with the count and total rows.  I will try your select statement and see how it goes.

Comment: your select statement returns the unique tag count correctly, but the TotalRows is not.  When I run your select query, I got 3,585 for TotalRows on each unique tag.  TotalRows should be 35.

Comment: @Juniuz I fixed it.  Realize that I can't easily test the queries I posted, because you gave no reprodicible sample data.

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate it.  I also google `WITH` statement, so this is a common table expression.  Is this similar to a variable or temp table?

Comment: @Juniuz Sort of.  A CTE will just be inlined into the actual query before the query is run.  So it is the same as just placing the code into the query.  I used a CTE because it makes things easier to read.

Comment: Okay, makes sense now.